# Sidewall rubber cut off damage

Tags: damage, sidewall-damage, tires

Hi Should i consider repairs or something for sidewall rubber cut off? I was driving this weekend 130kmh~80mph no problem was manifested. [image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a significant gouge in the sidewall which could potentially weaken its structure leading to a blow out. It may not happen right away, but the chances of it happening in this area are very much increased.

There's no repair for sidewalls, so in the interest of safety, you should replace the tire.

Comment: Hi, today i went to a volcanizer he said not to worry at all the damage is small, i will post more photos where you can see from other angle.